# JSON.stringify(ComplexArray) returns an empty string

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have the following JavaScript which utilises JQuery and Knockout (I have specific reasons for using the 2 together)

```
$(document).ready(
  function () {
      var Crime = function (Id, CaseNumber, DateOfIncident, Description) {
          var self = this;
          self.Id = Id;
          self.CaseNumber = CaseNumber;
          self.DateOfIncident = DateOfIncident;
          self.Description = Description;
      }

      var CrimesViewModel = function () {
          var self = this;
          //Data
          self.items = ko.observableArray()

          //operations
          addCrime = function () {
              if ($("#AddCrimeForm").valid()) {
                  crime = new Crime(0,
                      $("#AddCrimeForm #CaseNumber").val(),
                      $("#AddCrimeForm #DateOfIncident").val(),
                      $("#AddCrimeForm #Description").val());

                  self.items.push(this.crime);

                  $("#AddCrimeForm #CaseNumber").val("");
                  $("#AddCrimeForm #DateOfIncident").val("");
                  $("#AddCrimeForm #Description").val("");
              }
          }

          self.removeCrime = function (item) {
              self.items.remove(item);
          }

          loadCrimes = function (JSONstring) {
              try {
                  self.JSONItems = JSON.parse(JSONstring);
                  if (self.JSONItems != null)
                      if (self.JSONItems != null)
                          for (i = 0; i < self.JSONItems.length; i++)
                              self.items.push(self.JSONItems[i]);
              }
              catch (e) {
                  alert(e.message + "\n\n" + e.description + "\n\n" + e.stack)
              }
          }

          getCrimes = function () {
              var self = this;
              return JSON.stringify(self.items);
          }

      }

      var CrimesVM = new CrimesViewModel()

      ko.applyBindings(CrimesVM, $("#CrimeList")[0])

  }
);
```

As illustrated by the above code, I have a ViewModel which basically consists of an array containing `Crime` objects.

It is the intent of the `getCrimes()` function to, when called, serialise the array into JSON.

The `getCrimes()` function, unfortunately, returns an empty string, due to the fact that `JSON.stringify(self.items)` returns an empty string.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

**

### UPDATE

**

Here is the working code, based on the answer given below:

```
$(document).ready(
  function () {
      var Crime = function (Id, CaseNumber, DateOfIncident, Description) {
          var self = this;
          self.Id = Id;
          self.CaseNumber = CaseNumber;
          self.DateOfIncident = DateOfIncident;
          self.Description = Description;
      }

      var CrimesViewModel = function () {
          var self = this;
          //Data
          self.items = ko.observableArray()

          //operations
          addCrime = function () {
              if ($("#AddCrimeForm").valid()) {
                  crime = new Crime(0,
                      $("#AddCrimeForm #CaseNumber").val(),
                      $("#AddCrimeForm #DateOfIncident").val(),
                      $("#AddCrimeForm #Description").val());

                  self.items.push(this.crime);

                  //Update the correspoding hidden field
                  $("#CrimeCollection_New").val(ko.toJSON(self));

                  $("#AddCrimeForm #CaseNumber").val("");
                  $("#AddCrimeForm #DateOfIncident").val("");
                  $("#AddCrimeForm #Description").val("");                  
              }
          }

          self.removeCrime = function (item) {
              self.items.remove(item);
              //Update the correspoding hidden field
              $("#CrimeCollection_New").val(ko.toJSON(self));
          }

          loadCrimes = function (JSONstring) {
              try {
                  self.JSONItems = JSON.parse(JSONstring);
                  if (self.JSONItems != null)
                      if (self.JSONItems != null)
                          for (i = 0; i < self.JSONItems.length; i++)
                              self.items.push(self.JSONItems[i]);
              }
              catch (e) {
                  alert(e.message + "\n\n" + e.description + "\n\n" + e.stack)
              }
          }



      }

      var CrimesVM = new CrimesViewModel()

      ko.applyBindings(CrimesVM, $("#CrimeList")[0])

  }
);
```

Comment: I'm sure you have a great reason for using jQuery and Knockout together but your code is hard to follow for that reason.  Try getting the value of self.items with self.items()

Comment: Does the items Array actually contain any values? Have you tried debugging with Firebug / Chrome Developer tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `self.items` is a Knockout observable, you should use the Knockout function `.toJS()` to get the values: `ko.toJS(self.items)`.

Or, if you want to convert the items directly to JSON, you can use `.toJSON()`.

[Knockout: Loading and saving JSON data](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html)

Comment: Fantastic!  I actually knew about this a couple of days ago but have been grafting day-and-night to make a deadline - forgot about it in the process.  Thanks for pointing this out, this is just what I needed!  I will post my new working code for whomever needs it.  I guess I need to catch up on some sleep.